Cannot create react native project Installing pods failed
I am creating a react native project and got this error.

Downloading template
error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed. 
However, you will need to install pods manually when running iOS, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for iOS" section.

info  To enable automatic CocoaPods installation when building for iOS you can create react-native.config.js with automaticPodsInstallation field. 
For more details, see https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/projects.md#projectiosautomaticpodsinstallation
            

  
  Run instructions for Android:
    • Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
    • cd "/Users/khuongtai/Downloads/AwesomeProject" && npx react-native run-android
  
  Run instructions for iOS:
    • cd "/Users/khuongtai/Downloads/AwesomeProject/ios"
    
    • Install Cocoapods
      • bundle install # you need to run this only once in your project.
      • bundle exec pod install
      • cd ..
    
    • npx react-native run-ios
    - or -
    • Open AwesomeProject/ios/AwesomeProject.xcodeproj in Xcode or run "xed -b ios"
    • Hit the Run button
    
  Run instructions for macOS:
    • See https://aka.ms/ReactNativeGuideMacOS for the latest up-to-date instructions.


I checked the folder and it was empty. I really don't know how I tried with older versions and it still happens.
So is there any way to fix it?

I'm encountering the same thing on an Apple M3 machine.
edit: also found this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/46028

There will be another update tonight or tomorrow morning.

@KhuongVietTai this is 2 weeks ago and issue still persists in 0.75.2

It seems there is a temporary issue specific to 0.75.0. Using a previous version worked for me: npx react-native init MyNewProject --version 0.74.4

It really worked

⚠️ The init command is deprecated.
The behavior will be changed on 12/31/2024 (44 days).

Switch to npx @react-native-community/cli init for the identical behavior.
Refer to the documentation for information about alternative tools: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started

Running: npx @react-native-community/cli init
Need to install the following packages:
@react-native-community/cli@15.1.2

The template is downloading if you are using --pm npm at the end.
I used this command and it worked:
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init YourProjectName --pm npm

Thank you for the workaround. However, still broken with yarn.
